# What counts for longest headshot?

Tags: battlefield-4

So I can see in my detailed stats that my longest headshot is 154m

[image: Longest Headshot 154.68]

However I have also got 3 Marksman ribbons, which are awarded for a 250m headshot.

[image: Marksman Ribbon]

Why is my longest headshot statistic not shown as 250m or longer? Does the ribbon only count for shots with a sniper rifle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description is very misleading.

When you get a headshot that's over 50 meters, you get a Marksman score bonus (1 point per meter). If you accumulate 250 Makrsman bonus points in a round, you get 1 Marksman ribbon.

Example: If you make 5 x 50 meter headshots, you get 1 Marksman ribbon, or 2 x 125 meter headshot.

Every weapon counts.

Source: [BF Forum](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/en/forum/threadview/2955064767656637610/)

Comment: Your source is for BF3. Does this still apply for BF4?

Comment: It's just the BF3 forum. The source is in the Battlefield 4 - General Discussions section.

Comment: Edited the link to the BF4 battlelog